# Menu Design - Add More menu option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I need a menu, `html+jquery` where it must show all the menu in normal mode, when i go to responsive more only some menu must be visible and other menu must be under more where it must be generated automatically similar to this link

https://www.amazon.com/stores/Ozeri/node/2598028011

Suppose if zoom in or zoom out of browser I need to add some menu automatically to that more option generated.

PS: [If link does not work please copy paste it]

Check My source Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ozeri :: Ozeri Pro II Digital Kitchen Scale with Removable Glass Platform and Countdown Kitchen Timer (1 g to 12 lbs Capacity) </title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="img/favicon.png" />
    <!-- web-fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Style CSS -->
    <link href="css/ozeri-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link href="css/quick-view-img.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- slider -->
    <link href="css/thumbs2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/thumbnail-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="css/thumbnail-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
.popup-big-img { width: auto; height: 500px; text-align: center}
.popup-big-img img{ width: auto; height: 100%; }
.popup-small-img{width: 50px;height: 50px; margin:5px;float: left; border: 2px solid #ccc;}
.popup-small-img img{ width: 100%; height: 100%}
.modal-dialog.pro-popup{ width: 95%}
.popup-small-img:hover{border: 2px solid #004b91; cursor: pointer}
.popup-small-img-test{border: 2px solid #ff8f00;}
.modal-header.no-border{ border: none;}
h4.modal-title{ color: #000; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; margin: 10px 5px}
.a-row {margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 10px;float: left; }
.color-select{float: left; width: 70%}
.a-form-label {font-weight: 700;}
.manufacturer img{ text-align: center; display: inline-table;}
.product-color{ width: 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-inner">
<nav class="navbar m-menu navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid container-inner">
        <div class="search-input hidden-mobile" style="display: none">
   <input class="form-control top-search-box" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" type="text">
  </div>
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>--> 
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left main-nav">
                <li><a href="category.html" title="Barware">Barware</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-toggle"><a href="category.html" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Glassware">Glassware <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="category.html" title="Moderna Artisan Glassware">Moderna Artisan Glassware</a></li>
      <li><a href="category.html" title="Serafina Artisan Glassware">Serafina Artisan Glassware</a></li>
      <li><a href="category.html" title="Curva Artisan Glassware">Curva Artisan Glassware</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>
                <li><a href="category.html" title="Kitchen Scales">Kitchen Scales</a></li>
                <li><a href="category.html" title="Kitchecn Accessories">Kitchen Accessories</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-toggle">
                <a href="category.html" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Cookware">Cookware <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="category.html" title="Ceramic Earth Series">Ceramic Earth Series</a></li>
      <li><a href="category.html" title="Stone Earth Series">Stone Earth Series</a></li>
      <li><a href="category.html" title="Stainless Steel Series">Stainless Steel Series</a></li>
      <li><a href="category.html" title="Professional Series">Professional Series</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>
                <li><a href="category.html" title="Oscillatting Fans">Oscillatting Fans</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <li><a href="#">Bath and Personal Care</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Novelty</a></li>
    </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- .navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
 </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is showing page not found

Comment: If link does not work please copy paste it

Comment: Can you include the code you have tried so far?

Comment: please check i have added

Answer (score 0):

try to

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var item_width = $('#menu_ul li').width();
     var item_count = ($( "#menu_ul li" ).length);
     var nav_width_og = $('.menu').width();
     var nav_width = $('.menu').width();
      
     if ((item_width*(item_count+1)) > nav_width ){
         $('#more').appendTo('body');
      $('#more').hide();
    }
      
     for(var i = 0; i < item_count; i++) {
      nav_width = $('.menu').width();
    item_width = $('#menu_ul li').width();
    item_count = ($( "#menu_ul li" ).length); 
       
     if (nav_width<(item_width*item_count)){
    $('#menu_ul li').not('#more').last().appendTo($('.overflow'));
      
      $('#more').appendTo($('#menu_ul'));
      $('#more').show();
    }
     }
    
     
    $(window).resize(function(){ 
      
    nav_width = $('.menu').width();
    item_width = $('#menu_ul li').width();
    item_count = ($( "#menu_ul li" ).length);
    
    if (nav_width<(item_width*item_count)){
    $('#menu_ul li').not('#more').last().appendTo($('.overflow'));
      
      $('#more').appendTo($('#menu_ul'));
      $('#more').show();
    }
      
    if (nav_width>(item_width*item_count)+(item_width-1)){
     $('.overflow li').last().appendTo($('#menu_ul'));
      
      $('#more').appendTo($('#menu_ul'));
    }
       
    if (nav_width == nav_width_og ){
         $('#more').appendTo('body');
      $('#more').hide();
    }
      
    });
      
      $('#more').click(function(){
       $('.overflow').slideToggle(); 
      });
      });
```

```css
.menu{
  position:relative;
  max-width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:red;
 font-size:0px;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
  background:green;
  font-size:16px;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
.overflow{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  display:none;
}
.overflow li{
  display:block;
    background:yellow;
}
#more{
  background:blue;
  display:none;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul id="menu_ul">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
     <li>item7</li>
    <li>item8</li>
    <li>item9</li>
    <li>item10</li>
    <li>item11</li>
    <li>item12</li>

    <li id="more">more</li>
  </ul>
     <ul class="overflow">
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: say suppose any dropdown for item2, can u please update the code

Answer (score 0):

As like in your given amazon link, it has a menu named 'MORE'. 'MORE' has sub-menu 'Novelty' while in large screen/desktop.
If it goes in smaller screen like for mobile/tab screen sizes, if we click on 'MORE', a modal menu bar comes.
I think, you want like this.

To do this, you will need JS/jQuery. 
Step 1: for large screen/desktop sizes, just CSS dropdown menu is OK. Just have that 'MORE' with sub-menu using ul/li, you might be using bootstarp.

Step 2: You can have a hidden div with a modal(bootstarp modal or any other modal) having menu items inside and a 'close' button to close the modal. On clcik 'MORE' link, just call the modal by JS.
You need to check smaller screen sizes by JS. Bootstap modal has both HTML tag attribute way or [some methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript) to call and close.
bootstrap 4 modal doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

You can style that modal by CSS as you need. There are many jQuery modal plugin or can use bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked for any dropdown for item2 and others.
this will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <!-- Brand -->


        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Barware</a>
            </li>
            <!-- Dropdown -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Glassware</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kitchen Scales</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kitchen Accessories</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    cookware<div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Osciallating Fans</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <br>


    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/kdbnq2tx/